# Find $a_1/a_2$ in the Laurent series expansion of $\frac{1}{2z^2-13z+15}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\sum a_n z^n $ be the laurent series expansion of $f(z)=\frac{1}{2z^2-13z+15}$ in the annulus $3/2 <|z|<5$.

I am interested in finding $a_1/a_2$.

Efforts:

$f(z)=1/(2z-3)(z-10)$

So using partial fraction decomposition $$f(z)=\frac{1}{7} (\frac{1}{z-10}-\frac{1}{2z-3})$$

How should I proceed from here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ for $|z|<1$.

Comment: Your factorization of the denominator is incorrect: $2z^2-13z+15\neq(2z-3)(z-10)$.